# How does CakePHP 2 create a table?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am having trouble understanding how the model class can create a table in the database.

If I wanted a table with fields users and password, wherein CakePHP do I define these fields? It seems like, in the examples I've seen, that these fields are validated in the model. But where are they defined or initialized?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

CakePHP models don't create the database tables for you. They are a means of accessing existing tables that you have created. If you follow CakePHP's naming conventions the models just automatically know which tables they relate to; singular CamelCased model names relate to plural snake_cased tables.

To create your database tables you can either do this manually, or use CakePHP schemas to manage the database structure. There's also the excellent CakeDC migrations plugin for managing changes to the database structure.

- [CakePHP Schema management](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/schema-management-and-migrations.html)
- [CakeDC Migrations plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/migrations)

When a model is used in CakePHP it can determine the fields that belong to the model by running a SQL `DESCRIBE` query on the database table. This is done using the `Model::schema()` method. Cake caches the query results so that it doesn't need to keep querying the database for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , sure , You can control database's table with its fields ,Model name should be the same of table name , in any controller you can load

`$this->loadModel('SomeModel')
 $mydata=$this->tableName->find('all');
 $myuse =$this->set('myuse' , $mydata);`

in your view , The name of view should be the same of your Controller's function name:

`<h1> <?php echo $myuse['tableName']['fieldName]; ?></h1>`

Comment: And Also you can validate  in your  modal  , https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html

Comment: Something wrong , did you implement that ? , I am sure , you can find answer above post

Answer (score -1):

It not required to same name model as database table

like my table name is users and i create a model User

then you can define this table with User model in model > User.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
 class User extends AppModel
{
   public $name = 'User';
   public $useTable = 'users';
   public $primaryKey = 'id';
}
```